# How can I get a mesh or a surface through the use of the two curves?

Tags: graphics

I have two questions.

The first question seems to be well simple:

1. How could I show two curves in distinct planes in the same graphic or plotting?

My attempts:

These are the points that define the first curve in the Plane XY

```
datacurve1={{0,0},{45,20},{90,-20},{135,0}};
```

Here I yields a equation that defines the relationship between values of X-axis and Y-axis

```
curve1=Fit[datacurve1,{1,x,x^2,x^3,x^4},x];
```

The `curve 1` represents the values in the `Plane XY`

```
gr1=Plot[curve1,{x,0,135},AxesLabel->{X,Y},PlotLabel->"PlaneXY",LabelStyle->{GrayLevel[0]}]
```

These are the points that define the first curve in the Plane ZY

```
datacurve2={{0,0},{25,15},{50,0},{100,15}}
```

Here I yields a equation that defines the relationship between values of Z-axis and Y-axis

```
curve2=Fit[datacurve2,{1,z,z^2,z^3,z^4},z]
```

The `curve 2` represents the values in the `PlaneZY`

```
gr2=Plot[curve2,{z,0,100},AxesLabel->{Z,Y},PlotLabel->"PlaneZY",LabelStyle->{GrayLevel[0]}]
```

This is the only way I know do to show the two plots, but this is not what I want. I tried to use `Graphics3D`, but I don´t know how do it

```
Show[gr1,gr2]
```

I would like that the result was something as shown in the image below:

[image]

The second question is this:

2. How can I get a mesh or a surface through the use of these two curves as shown in image below? I tried to find the word suitable for this question, but I don´t know which would be...

[image]

Comment: The animation was unsuccessful. I will try to update later.

Comment: You can use `GeometricTransformation` and friends

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems to me this is what you want:

```
Plot3D[curve1 + curve2, {x, 0, 135}, {z, 0, 100}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Or perhaps this, if the shading is important:

```
Plot3D[curve1 + curve2, {x, 0, 135}, {z, 0, 100}, 
 MeshShading -> {{Black, Gray}, {Gray, Black}}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

If not, then please clarify the question.

Comment: What I need to do to achieve a similar result to the first question image?

Comment: @Leandro, use `ParametricPlot3D[]` for space curves.

Comment: I was referring to with this image: `http://i.stack.imgur.com/mCTPD.jpg`. If it was about her that said, forgive me but I don't understand how to use.